# keyup binding and updateAttribute in spine.js only grabbing first few characters of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, spine.js

I'm working with a spine.js application and a django restful backend. A simple binding for a keyup event on an input fires off a function in my controller that tries to updateAttribute a certain model record. I did a log.console in the controller and it seems that all the values getting passed to updateAttribute are correct, and the record is indeed updated. However when I run my app the database table is updated with only the first (or first few) characters in the input field -- and not the entire string that is being passed to the file.

Any idea why this might be happening? Why would updateAttribute only grab the first character of a string and update the record, rather than the whole thing? Been trying to fix this bug for a while today and very frustrated.

Below are relevant excerpts from my code:

```
# below are my key bindings for keyup in my input fields and textareas 
events:
  'click a.social-tab' : 'selectTab'
  'keyup input' : 'updateDraggableText'
  'keyup textarea' : 'updateDraggableText'

# ...

# below are excerpts for my callback function
# below grabs the record to be updated
draggable = @parent.draggables()[index]

# update field attribute with value of txt
draggable.updateAttribute field, txt
```

Comment: Further experimenting may be that the requests are being sent to the backend too quickly: if i type very slowly, one key at a time, it seems to update the record correctly. But I have to type extremely slowly for this, like 3/4 or 1 second in between keys.

Would anyone have any suggestions on overcoming this problem in a spine.js environment? It must have happened to other people

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting it seems that the django backend was not honoring PUT requests with updates after too many rapid, frequent connections (i.e., one request with each key pressed). For now I fixed this in the front end, by queueing up updateAttribute called with a setTimeout, storing the reference (return) in a global variable, and calling clearTimeout if another updateAttribute request was requested before the previous one had executed. This way only the last (relevant) update to the record is made while typing is happening.

Comment: you can add ajax: false as an option arg when calling functions that would otherwise trigger ajax. For your use case have you considered maybe a blur event rather than a keyup event?

Comment: Blur event is a good idea, but probably not sufficient to my needs. Any data entered into the form must be saved, wether or not the user steps away from the keyboard before they hit "enter" or a submit button. Not sure what you mean by the first part of your comment -- "add ajax: false as an option arg"

Comment: on a spine model that is using ajax a POST or PUT will be automatically triggered any time you do a modelItem.save(), but you can prevent this by passing a arg like modelItem.save({ajax:false})